# increasing the height of particular bar in vertical bar chart

Tags: html, css

I am using a vertical bar chart from the site::
https://codepen.io/anythinggraphic/pen/xxKpBax

```
/* Bar Graph Vertical */
.bar-graph .year {
  -webkit-animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
  animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
}

.bar-graph-vertical {
  margin-top: -109px;
  max-width: 680px;
}

.bar-graph-vertical .bar-container {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}

.bar-graph-vertical .bar {
  border-radius: 3px;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
}

.bar-graph-vertical .year {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bar-graph-two .bar::after {
  -webkit-animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
  animation: fade-in-text 2.2s 0.1s forwards;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-percentage);
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  top: 24px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bar-graph-two .bar-one .bar {
  background-color: #64b2d1;
  -webkit-animation: show-bar-one-vertical 1.2s 0.1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: show-bar-one-vertical 1.2s 0.1s forwards;
  animation: show-bar-one-vertical 1.2s 0.1s forwards;
}

.bar-graph-two .bar-two .bar {
  background-color: #5292ac;
  -webkit-animation: show-bar-two-vertical 1.2s 0.2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: show-bar-two-vertical 1.2s 0.2s forwards;
  animation: show-bar-two-vertical 1.2s 0.2s forwards;
}

.bar-graph-two .bar-three .bar {
  background-color: #407286;
  -webkit-animation: show-bar-three-vertical 1.2s 0.3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: show-bar-three-vertical 1.2s 0.3s forwards;
  animation: show-bar-three-vertical 1.2s 0.3s forwards;
}

.bar-graph-two .bar-four .bar {
  background-color: #2e515f;
  -webkit-animation: show-bar-four-vertical 1.2s 0.4s forwards;
  -moz-animation: show-bar-four-vertical 1.2s 0.4s forwards;
  animation: show-bar-four-vertical 1.2s 0.4s forwards;
}
```

I have posted the CSS code block from the site but please refer to the site.
I have to increase the height of a particular bar labelled "2017". I am unable to do that. I tried with inspect element but can't do it. Please can any one help me with this. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways:
1)
**inline css on line 109**

```
100% {
    height: 108%;
}
```

or
2)
`<div class="bar" data-percentage="68%" style="height: 120% !important;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

if you use and fill `data-percentage` on your server side, you could also fill a css [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) value meanwhile and use that var to update size and label from CSS.

[`Writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) is also an option to rotate your text.

example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  --bar: clamp(220px, 40vh, 500px);/* whatever you need here */
  min-height:100vh;/*demo purpose */
  display:flex;/*demo purpose */
}
body{margin:auto;/*demo purpose */}
ul {
  font-size:clamp(10px, 4vmin, 16px);/* whatever you need here */
  height: var(--bar);
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  padding-top:0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  width:max-content;/*demo purpose */
  margin:auto;/*demo purpose */
  background:#bee;
  border-radius:0.25em;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;/*demo purpose */
  transition: 0.2s
}
ul:hover {transform:rotate(-90deg);/*demo purpose */}
li {
  width:2em;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  animation: show-bar-vertical 1.2s 0.4s forwards;
}
b {
  margin-bottom: -4em;
  padding:0.5em;
  background:#adf
}
span {
 
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  flex: 1 1;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  overflow:hidden; 
  max-height:0;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 2px white,-1px -1px 2px gray;
  animation:delay 0.1s 0.25s forwards
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-percentage);
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-indent: .5em; 
  height:0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) b {background:#aef;}
li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-color: #64b2d1;
}

li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-color: #5292ac;
}

li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-color: #407286;
}

li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-color: #2e515f;
}

li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-color: #1e3d49;
}

@keyframes show-bar-vertical {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: var(--data-percentage,auto);
  }
}
@keyframes delay{
  to {max-height:100%;}
}
```

```html
<!-- example build from a list, structure can be anything else -->
<ul id="bargraph">
  <li style="--data-percentage : 40% ">
    <span data-percentage=" 40%" ></span>
    <b>2020</b>
  </li>
  <li style="--data-percentage : 55% ">
    <span data-percentage=" 55%" ></span>
    <b>2019</b>
  </li>
  <li style="--data-percentage : 100% " >
    <span data-percentage=" 100%" ></span>
    <b>2018</b>
  </li>
  <li style="--data-percentage : 82% ">
    <span  data-percentage=" 82%" ></span>
    <b>2017</b>
  </li>
  <li style="--data-percentage : 25% ">
    <span data-percentage=" 25%" ></span>
    <b>2016</b>
  </li>  
</ul>
```